Splunk query for pattern matching
I have openshift log configured in splunk and below API results capturing under "log{}" and "pod_name" available under kubernate (kubernate.pod_name). API response time is capturing in the result last 234 ms. I want to fetch only that response time against each distinct pod name.

Blockquote

Log
[
10.234.21.1 GET api/proditem/taskid/ HTTP 1.1 200 - 234 ms
]
Expected table result
Host          average_response_time
33h_iei566_pod1     250 ms
33h_iei566_pod2     230 ms
33h_iei566_pod3     340 ms
I tried below
index=apps_openshift_huge Source="automate_pod*" log | rex field=message "(?<response_time>\d+)\ms" | table host, response_time

